# Huge time in slow query log (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

When I run the slow query log analyzer, I see huge time of requests in seconds. I tried to execute these requests manually, they are executed very fast(0.01sec). What could be the problem?

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'192.168.1.101' EVENT `DEL_EXPIRED_BANS`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE STARTS '2013-10-18 13:38:54'
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
  ENABLE
  COMMENT ''  DO
BEGIN
update users set ban_type=0, ban_expire=null, ban_expire=null, ban_reason=null 
 where ban_type > 0 and ban_expire < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
 delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,4, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=1;
  delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,4, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=0;
END;
```

[root@xy1 GameServer]# mysqldumpslow -a -s t -t 15 /var/log/mysql_slow.log

```
Reading mysql slow query log from /var/log/mysql_slow.log
Count: 1344  Time=18446679593472.00s (24792337373626364s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=41408.5 (55653024), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), 2users@localhost
  update users set ban_type=0, ban_expire=null, ban_expire=null, ban_reason=null
  where ban_type > 0 and ban_expire < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Count: 672  Time=18446679593471.92s (12396168686813130s)  Lock=0.15s (98s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=33953.0 (22816416), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@localhost
  delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=1

Count: 672  Time=18446679593471.92s (12396168686813128s)  Lock=0.15s (100s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=33953.0 (22816416), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@localhost
  delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,3, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=0

Count: 672  Time=18446679593471.91s (12396168686813120s)  Lock=0.09s (63s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=14599.2 (9810684), Rows_affected=22.5 (15144), root[root]@192.168.1.101
  delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,4, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=1

Count: 672  Time=18446679593470.33s (12396168686812064s)  Lock=1.70s (1140s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=28865.1 (19397320), Rows_affected=0.4 (237), root[root]@192.168.1.101
  delete from `flash_client_log` where TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,4, `dttm` ) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and `log_type`=0

Count: 1  Time=18446679639052.95s (18446679639052s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=0.0 (0), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), billiards3d_net[billiards3d_net]@localhost
  delete from guests_log WHERE dttm < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: Apparently you have `log_queries_not_using_indexes=on`, and you hit a bug which affects queries meeting the criteria and executed via events. A bug report has been filed based on this question: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11552 . The bug will be fixed in future versions of MariaDB. Meanwhile, if you aren't really in the process of analyzing queries not using indexes, you can set the variable `off` (if you do it in the config, you need to restart the server; if you do it at runtime, make sure it's a global value that you are changing, and restart `event_scheduler`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I thought the queries so slow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099516/huge-time-in-slow-query-log-mariadb#comment69418645_41099516), a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11552) was filed based on this question. The bug has now been fixed, the [fix](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/e86580c3dda707788fb0ca35244cf602d7e8d50d) is available in [5.5 tree](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/tree/5.5) and will be released with the next releases of MariaDB: 5.5.54, 10.0.29, 10.1.21, 10.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

The clock runeth backward.  You need to take it easy -- do not exceed the speed of light!

Seriously, ...  I have seen this periodically for the past 15 years, in all versions of MySQL.  The number you are seeing is probably `-1` being treated as a `UNSIGNED` number.

Recommendation:  think of it as zero, and move on.

OK, that is hard to do in this case, since you have a summary (mysqldumpslow).  The source of the problem is somewhere in the slowlog.  If it happens again tomorrow (over a different part of the slowlog), file a bug with http://bugs.mysql.com (assuming there are not already several there).